# android app using Socket IO not logging in

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

I'm creating an app in Android using Socket.IO. I am stuck at the Login itself. Here is my code for Login

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText uname_et, pwd_et;
    Button log;
    String username, password;
    private Socket mSocket;
    private Emitter.Listener onLogin = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.e(args[0].toString(), "data");
            Log.w("yes ", "in evtLogin");
            //   JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];

        }
    };

    {
        try {
            String URL = "http://MYIP:8081";
            mSocket = IO.socket(URL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uname_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_input);
        pwd_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
        log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signin();
            }
        });

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.i("Make Emit", "Emit");
                Log.w(mSocket.connected() + " - ", "Connection status");
            }

        });
        mSocket.on("evtLogin", onLogin);
        mSocket.connect();
    }

    private void signin() {
        username = uname_et.getText().toString();
        password = pwd_et.getText().toString();
        mSocket.emit("userName", username);
        mSocket.emit("Password", password);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mSocket.off("evtLogin", onLogin);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure that socket is even connected or not, I'm gettong logs from `Socket.EVENT_CONNECT`

```
08-31 12:22:22.062  13399-13441/com.fis.kotsocket I/Make Emit﹕ Emit
08-31 12:22:22.063  13399-13441/com.fis.kotsocket W/true -﹕ Connection status
```

But onLogin listener is not called.
As a newbie I am not sure what to do exactly.

js code

```
 //code for login event

        socket.on('evtLogin', function (loginData) {
            console.log('loged');
           User.findOne({'login.userName':loginData.userName,'login.password':loginData.password},function(err,user){

                if(err){throw err;}
                else {if(!user){

                    console.log('not a authenticated user');
                }
                else
                {
                    var userType;
                    User.find({'login.userName':loginData.userName,'login.password':loginData.password},function(err,rslt){
                        if(err){throw err;}
                        else
                        {
                            userType = JSON.stringify(rslt[0]['userType'].userId);
                            socket.emit('evtUserType',userType);
                        }
                    })
                }
                }

            });
        console.log('done');

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your socket is not getting initialized.
Try this initialization:

```
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("enter url here");

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
}
```

Or it might be that you are not emitting the `evtLogin` event from your javascript code.

Comment: ya ..u were right `evtLogin` wasn't emitting from the server. I got it working now.